# how to make graph command for discord.py?

Tags: python, math, graph, discord.py

So I am trying to make a command that graphs an equation for discord.py that takes the equation and graphs it. I am using mathplotlib for the command, but the command says that it has graphed the line, but everytime it graphs the default line, which is x^2, or x ** 2. Here is my code for the command:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox

@client.command()
async def graph(ctx, *, equation):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
    t = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, 0.001)
    s = t ** 2
    initial_text = equation
    l, = plt.plot(t, s, lw=2)


    def submit(text):
        ydata = eval(text)
        l.set_ydata(ydata)
        ax.set_ylim(np.min(ydata), np.max(ydata))
        plt.draw()

    axbox = plt.axes([0.1, 0.05, 0.8, 0.075])
    text_box = TextBox(axbox, 'Evaluate', initial=initial_text)
    text_box.on_submit(submit)

    plt.savefig('graph.png')
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File('graph.png'))
```

Comment: `everytime it graphs the default line, which is x^2, or x ** 2` -- well, your call to plot (`plt.plot(t, s, lw=2)`) does not depend on input in any way. If you want to plot the equation, you'd need to parse it and pass it to plot.

Comment: so how would I do that?

Comment: You could parse the `equation` variable from the command to create the line on your graph.

Comment: `def submit(text): ydata = eval(text)`  <---- What is this intended to do? it looks super dangerous. The user can type any text, and you will evaluate it as python code with `eval`? What is the user types in `"os.system('rm -rf /')"`, which means "delete everything I can from this computer"? See this answer: [Allowing a program to execute arbitrary user input is bad](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/311510)

Comment: ok, so what are you indicating?